# Cucumber arity mismatch: trying to bind several matching groups to a single stepdef parameter

Tags: java, regex, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match the following:

```
Given I'm a user
Given I am a user
Given Dylan is a user
```

And this is my step definition:

```java
@Given("^(?:(I)'m|(I) am|(.+) is) a user$")
public void aUserExists(String username) throws Throwable {
}
```

It's matching what I need, but seems like Cucumber is trying to assign each capturing group in the non-capturing group to a parameter, while I want it to assign just one:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'hello.MyStepdefs.aUserExists(String) in [...] with pattern [^(?:(I)'m|(I) am|(.+) is) a user$] is declared with 1 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 3 arguments [I, null, null].

I'm coming from PHP background and this regular expression worked great with [Behat](http://behat.org/). Maybe I'm not getting something about Java regular expressions or Cucumber behavior.

---

**Update**

Since all the current answers are having the same problem, I'm updating the question.

I don't want to match a string like:

```
Given I is a user
```

I want to match `I` only when it's followed by `'m` or `am`. I hope it's not an impossible thing to do with Java regular expressions and Cucumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you are looking for but if you want to capture user name in  group one without creating more groups then maybe try

```
"^(\\w+)(?:(?<=I\\b)(?:'m| am)|(?<!^I\\b) is) a user$"
```

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov you can also use [pobrelkey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20447630/1393766) with little improvement `@Given("^(I(?='m| am)|(?!I\\b).+(?= is))(?:'m| am| is) a user$")`

Comment: @downvoter thanks, I am closer to unsung-hero now. But just from curiosity, why are you willing to spend your reputation to help me get this badge?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the regex to use only one capturing group, though it gets ugly:

```
@Given("^(I(?='m| am)|.+(?= is))(?:'m| am| is) a user$")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arity mismatch:` does nothing to do with your regex, rather your `Given I'm a user` line is mismatching with your method signature `public void aUserExists(String username) throws Throwable {
}` take out the string argument and try again.